# Prevent C# class from implementing any method other than what is defined in an interface

Tags: c#, methods, interface

Is it possible in Visual Studio (C#) to define an interface with some method and force the class that implements this interface to have defined only the method that is defined in the interface, and prevent the class from defining any method not specified in the interface?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. May I ask why would you like to have this?

Comment: Nope, and if that was ever possible the person responsible would be chased down and stoned to death by angry developers.

Comment: I believe one could have a custom fxcop rule that would be checked upon compilation. He doesn't seem to want such feature in the language itself, rather in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If there is a specific case you have in mind you could ask about that and maybe there is an approach to your problem that doesn't require something that cannot be done in C#.  For instance maybe what you really want is a delegate and not an interface.

Comment: I don't really know why you'd want that.  Once you're dealing with the interface, you don't need to and shouldn't have to care about anything else but the API it defines.

Comment: I dont agree with hold, question IS CLEAR ever for non english readers. maybe positive answer dont exist, but that is different story.

Comment: If you pass the class around as the interface, whatever uses the interface won't be able to "see" the extra methods/properties anyway, so there is no reason to do this.

Comment: Agree, answer is negative, seems general rule in OO languages is "no" ... maybe too much (for me) absolutely stupid question with score >0 . This not belong to this group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge an interface is an inclusive contract, not an exclusive one. The way you want to deal with this is to make calls to you interface instantiation of the class instead of the concrete one. See the example below. In so doing, you limit your code to only seeing the specific methods defined by the interface.

Now, some will point out that you could write a framework, and use reflection to compare the interface methods to the class methods - but I don't suspect that is the OPs intent.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool AmITrue { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : IMyInterface
{
    public bool AmITrue { get; set; }
    public bool AmIAnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{

    public MainClass()
    {
        IMyInterface limitedClass = new Class1();

        var works = limitedClass.AmITrue;
        var doesNotWork = limitedClass.AmIAnotherProperty;
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably should rename `AmIAnotherMethod` to `AmIAnotherProperty`.

Comment: @juharr  doh!!! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.

But it really sounds like you are trying to define a `class` itself, wouldn't that achieve the same thing?

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Why implement an interface to a class to only allow that interfaces functions. Just don't implement the interface and define the necessary functions in that class...